# How to get a hierarchical Multipart request data in REST controller?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, multipart

There is a spring-mvc controller resource to receive files and store them in local storage. The request is a multipart ("Content-Type: multipart/form-data") and consists of few parts. The first part is JSON/XML description of files. The second and the following are files. But these parts may be multipart too ("Content-Type: multipart/mixed"). Few files in one part. Multipart in multipart.

```
POST /exampleAPI/nms/v1/myStore/tel%3A%2B19585550100/objects/operations/bulkCreation HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/xml
Authorization: BEARER 08776724-6d0d-4aa6-a404-2bc19b5cf903
Host: example.com
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary="===============outer123456==";
Content-Length: nnnn
MIME-Version: 1.0
--===============outer123456==
Content-Type: application/xml
Content-Disposition: form-data; name=”root-fields”
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<nms:objectList xmlns:nms="urn:oma:xml:rest:netapi:nms:1">
<object>
 <parentFolder>http://example.com/exampleAPI/nms/v1/myStore/tel%3A%2B19585550100/folders/fld123</parentFolder>
<attributes/>
 <flags>
 <flag>\Seen</flag>
 <flag>\Flagged</flag>
 </flags>
</object>
<object>
 <parentFolderPath>/Pictures</parentFolderPath>
 <attributes/>
 <flags>
 <flag>\Seen</flag>
 </flags>
</object>
</nms:objectList>
--===============outer123456==
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=”--=-sep-=--”
Content-Disposition: form-data; name=”attachments”
----=-sep-=--
Content-Type: text/plain
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=”body.txt”
See attached photo
----=-sep-=--
Content-Type: image/gif
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="picture.gif"
GIF89a...binary image data...
----=-sep-=----
--===============outer123456==
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=”--=-sep-=--”
Content-Disposition: form-data; name=”attachments”
----=-sep-=--
Content-Type: text/plain
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=”body.txt”
Photo from trip to Vancouver
----=-sep-=--
Content-Type: image/gif
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="picture.gif"
GIF89a...binary image data...
----=-sep-=----
--===============outer123456==--
```

I have to store them in groups according to the request structure. Body.txt and picture.gif from the second form-data part in one group, files from the third form-data in another. But using MultipartFile or Part or MultipartHttpServletRequest there is no information about nesting, all files on one level.

How I can receive multipart data in a hierarchy structure?

```
@RestController
public class AttachmentController {

@PostMapping(path = ("/upload"), consumes = {"multipart/form-data", "multipart/mixed"})
public Response uploadFiles(
        @RequestPart(value = "description") FilesDescription fileDesc,
        @RequestPart(value = "attachments", required = false) List<MultipartFile> attachments) {
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior refers to RFC 2388 which has been obsoleted by RFC 7578.

RFC 7578 4.3

> [RFC2388] suggested that multiple files for a single form field be
> transmitted using a nested "multipart/mixed" part.  This usage is
> deprecated.

> To match widely deployed implementations, multiple files MUST be sent
> by supplying each file in a separate part but all with the same
> "name" parameter.

> Receiving applications intended for wide applicability (e.g.,
> multipart/form-data parsing libraries) SHOULD also support the older
> method of supplying multiple files.

Most of all modern libraries implement RFC 7578 behavior. All parts of multipart/mixed content will be put in the same array because of the same name "name=attachments".

Based on this, the requirement to parse nested multipart/mixed hierarchically under multipart/form-data may be considered obsolete.